# Acquire instance from metaclass

Tags: ruby, metaclass

Given a metaclass in ruby (or eigenclass or singleton_class), how would I find the instance of that class?  To the best of my knowledge, metaclasses are intrinsically linked with a SINGLE instance of said metaclass.  Therefore, there should be a way to find the instance of it, right?

For example...

```
class Example
  def self.do_something
    "Hello everyone!"
  end
end

p Example #should output 'Example'
p Example.singleton_class #should output '#<Class:Example>'
```

I want a method that would do the following:

```
def meta_do_something(meta)
  #invokes the do_something method on the object that meta references
end

meta_do_something(Example.singleton_class) #should output "Hello everyone!"
```

I've been searching all around, but I can find nothing... any ideas?

Comment: This should answer your question: `class A; end; c = A.singleton_class => #<Class:A>; c.new =>
TypeError: can't create instance of singleton class`.

Comment: Singleton classes are just classes like any other. There is no reference from a class to its instances, only the other way round (every instance has a reference to its class). You might be able to do something by iterating over `ObjectSpace`, but note that that will be very expensive and also prone to race conditions against the GC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class (Example in your case) is not an instance of its singleton class. It is a sub-class. Sub-classes are not instances of their super-classes, they're just...well, sub-classes.  Instances are objects created with from `SomeClass` with `SomeClass.new`. There is a reason why Ruby makes meta-classes invisible. I guess your fundamental question is basically whether a super-class can know about its sub-class, and the answer is no, I'd imagine that would break a lot of OOP concepts (a dog is an animal, but not every animal is a dog).

It's true that `do_something` is an instance method of the Singleton class (all methods are instance methods in Ruby technically speaking) but the fact is that you cannot initialize a new Singleton class in a same way like you would initialize any other class. There's a reason why Ruby makes this class invisible (cannot be seen by calling .ancestors).

**Edit:** This is an (ugly) hack that does the job if you're looking to do this at all costs:

```
def meta_do_something(meta)
  actual_class = Object.const_get(meta.to_s[/(?<=#<Class:)[^>]+/])
  method_to_call =  meta.instance_methods(false)[0]
  actual_class.send(method_to_call)
end

meta_do_something(Example.singleton_class) #=> "Hello everyone!"
```

If you wanted to call all methods defined in the singleton class, you could do something like this  (replacing the 3rd and 4th line):

```
meta.instance_methods(false).each do |method|
    actual_class.send(method)
end
```

Comment: With all due respect, I'm not sure I honestly believe this explanation.  An instance method defined on a class is executable by it's instances.  Likewise, an instance method defined on a class's metaclass is executable by the class's singleton object.  Regardless of this, the inspect method on a class's metaclass returns a string that contains the class's name itself.  Is there any way, short of inspecting, ripping the name substring out, and doing an `Object.const_get` to acquire the class object?

Comment: Well, you can certainly force that name into a string, rip it using a regular expression, then get the actual method and send to it, see my updated answer. Not the most Rubyish way, but does the job..

Comment: "an Animal is a Dog, but not every Dog is an Animal, for example" I think you've got that backwards.

Comment: BTW I'm going to be doing more research into this tonight... I'll post here if I come up with any results.  Otherwise, this becomes the accepted answer, as it answers the question provided (regardless of the "how").

Comment: Well, from my research into the ruby source (or at least the one located http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source ), it looks like the metaclass -does- have an explicit reference to the object that 'belongs' to it.  See Class.c, macro HAVE_METACLASS_P().  It looks like it is being stored in the same table that the instance variables are stored in, using the string "__attached__".   Downside is, I don't see any (feasible or safe) way to access this __attached__ variable.  As I don't want to use a hack, I'll just have to find another way to accomplish my overall goal.